# ifsym: Document compiles successfully, but without correct output

Tags: symbols

I have MacOSX Leopard, TeXShop and have copied the `ifsym` package to `/usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-dist/doc/latex/`, available from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifsym
and successfully installed it etc. (updated my index: `sudo texhash`)

I tried to compile this piece of LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}
\begin{document}
$\FilledTriangleRight$
\end{document}
```

It compiles successfully but without the correct output, it prints a small italic letter 'd', I mean just d in the PDF.

Does anyone have an idea what I should do, so that it will print a filled triangle pointing to the left? (from the `ifsym` package of course, no others)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I cleaned up your question a bit, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commands of **ifsym** must not be used in math mode. If you need them in a formula, enclose them in `\mbox`. That's a not so nice "feature" of the package.

On an aside, you should be using `tlmgr` in order to install packages in TeX Live (or, on the Mac, **TeX Live Utility** that should be in your `/Applications/TeX` folder). Consider also to upgrade to TeX Live 2011 at http://tug.org/mactex

Answer (score 5):

Don't use math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}
 \begin{document}
\RightDiamond \FilledTriangleRight
 \end{document}
```

Btw: The fonts are bitmap fonts, they won't scale well in a pdf.